# How to make the autocomplete search result contains hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am doing a search box to search the items in a list. When users start to type in words, the original list fade out, while the list of matched items fade in, and the items in the list would contain some hyperlinks.

this is what I get right now, http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/sbAR6/5/.

I am using fadeIn, fadeOut to change the list, and autocomplete feature. 
something like this

`$(".form-search").keypress(function() {
    $("#nav-list123").fadeOut({});
    $("#search-result").fadeIn({});
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({}});`

However, I could not make the hyperlinks for the search result, it seems I need to customize the autocomplete code. Which I have no idea how to do it.

Could anyone helps me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can manually open link like that:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: source,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    window.location.href = ui.item.value; 
    //window.open(ui.item.value); // if you  want to open it in new tab

  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for help, however, i want the list of result could contain hyperlinks, not directly from the dropdown menu.

Comment: In this case you can just render it to HTML and replace it with AJAX

Comment: thanks, mainly not what i was looking for, but my supervisor just change my task. anyway, thanks for helping